# How to convert $\arctan(24/7) $to $2\arctan(3/4)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

This is actually a doubt I got while solving [this question](https://www.askiitians.com/forums/Discuss-with-Askiitians-Tutors/please-prove-the-following-2cos-1-3-root-13_114688.htm). The thing is I know how to convert $2\arctan(3/4)$ to $\arctan(24/7)$ by using the $\arctan x + \arctan y$ identity, but how do I do the opposite? Please help!

Comment: Please type your questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2\arctan\frac34\\=\arctan\left(\tan\left(2\arctan\frac34\right)\right)
\\=\arctan\left(\frac{2\tan\left(\arctan\dfrac34\right)}{1-\tan^2\left(\arctan\dfrac34\right)}\right)
\\=\arctan\left(\frac{\dfrac32}{1-\dfrac9{16}}\right)
\\=\arctan\frac{24}7$$

can be read top-down or bottom-up !

---

To discover the bottom-up formula, you need to solve

$$\frac{2y}{1-y^2}=x$$

which is a quadratic equation.

$$xy^2+2y-x=0$$ has the solutions

$$y=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}.$$

For the solutions to be rational, you need to use Pythagorean triples such as $(24,7)$ and

$$y=\frac{1+\dfrac{\sqrt{24^2+7^2}}7}{\dfrac{24}7}=\frac 43.$$

Comment: To do it bottom-up I have to resort to trial and error right?

Comment: @Hema: to be honest, bottom-up is infeasible ;-)

Comment: Why exactly is that so?

Comment: Bottom up you need intuition. You need to know what arctan is. You need to imagine that you need some sort of Pythagoras theorem and look for it. Of course, you don't have to go bottom up: if you start by $2\arctan y=\arctan \frac{24}{7}$ you can look for $y$ in a more standard way.

Comment: @Hema: I was a little kidding, see the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\tan(2x)=\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}$.

Comment: Would you please give a bit more detail? Though I can do it the reverse way I have no idea how to do the forward proof, and what to take as what based on this formula. Also according to the question I did there is no way of knowing beforehand what the RHS is to be.

Comment: @Hema Use this equality to compute $\tan\left(2\arctan\left(\frac34\right)\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(4+3i)^2 = 7+24i$ and take args.